# Riemann integral is zero for certain sets

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The question is:

Let $\pi=\left \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^n\;|\;x=(x_1,...,x_{n-1}, 0) \right \}$. Prove that if $E\subset\pi$ is a closed Jordan domain, and $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable, then $\int_{E}f(x)dV=0$.

(How to relate the condition it's Riemann integrable to the value is $0$? The textbook I use define $f$ is integrable on $E$ iff    $\;\;\;\;(L)\int_{E}fdV=(U)\int_{E}fdV$

$(L)\int_{E}fdV=\underset{G}{sup}L(f;G)$,

$(U)\int_{E}fdV=\underset{G}{inf}U(f;G)$,

$U(f;G)=\sum_{R_j\cap E\neq \varnothing }M_j|R_j|$ where $M_j=sup_{x\in R_j}f(x)$,

$L(f;G)=\sum_{R_j\cap E\neq \varnothing }m_j|R_j|$ where $m_j=inf_{x\in R_j}f(x)$.

$E$ is an Jordan region in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f$ is a bounded function,

$R$ is an n-dimensional rectangle s.t. $E\subseteq R$.

$G=\left \{ R_1,...,R_p \right \}$ is a grid on $R$.

(Extend $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by setting $f(x)=0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus E$.))

Can you use these backgrounds and terminologies to explain? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: what is the generalized volume of $\,E\,$ in $\,\Bbb R^n\,$ ? ... Well, there you go!

Comment: @DonAntonio: Can you explain clearer? Thanks.

Comment: I mean the Borel measure on $\,\Bbb R^n\,$ , which I guess you're working with, aren't you?

Comment: @DonAntonio: See my edited post. Can you use those backgrounds and terminologies to explain?